# How to create a table with a column that will automatically compute the sum of the other column using SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to create a table which will automatically compute the values of four other column to a table called totalAmount.

my SQL script won't work. Kindly guide me. Thanks.

This is my sql,

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.phicTF(
guid            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() PRIMARY KEY,
phno            NVARCHAR(14)        NOT NULL,
memLname        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
memFname        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
memMname        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pLname          NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pFname          NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pMname          NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
preltomem       NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
membership      NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pAge            NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pSex            NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
conDateFrom     DATE                NOT NULL,
conDateTo       DATE                NOT NULL,
icdCode         NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
fcRateFac       NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
fcRatePF        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
scRateFac       NVARCHAR(MAX)       NULL,
scRatePF        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NULL,
totalAmount  AS SUM(fcRateFac+fcRatePF+scRateFac+scRatePF)
```

)
GO

Comment: Data types exist for a reason. Do you really want the complete works of William Shakespeare inserted into the `pAge` column, for example?

Comment: Seconded. What does it mean to add text data together with text data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.phicTF(
guid            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() PRIMARY KEY,
phno            NVARCHAR(14)        NOT NULL,
memLname        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
memFname        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
memMname        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pLname          NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pFname          NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pMname          NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
preltomem       NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
membership      NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pAge            NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
pSex            NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
conDateFrom     DATE                NOT NULL,
conDateTo       DATE                NOT NULL,
icdCode         NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
fcRateFac       NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
fcRatePF        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
scRateFac       NVARCHAR(MAX)       NULL,
scRatePF        NVARCHAR(MAX)       NULL,
totalAmount  AS cast(fcRateFac as int)+cast(fcRatePF as int)+cast(scRateFac as int)+cast(scRatePF as int)

)
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

Define the `total` column as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and add a trigger on `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

In the trigger get values for the 4 columns sum them and assign to the `total` column.

Answer (score 0):

Declare TotalAmount as decimal(15,2)
while inserting values into the table make calculation for the totalamount column.

Create table t(col1 int,col2,int,....totalamount decimal(15,2)

insert into t(col1,col2,col3,totalamount) values(val1,val2,val3,val1+val2)